# RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey does not redirect to Wow6432Node folder when using RegistryView.Registry32

Tags: c#, .net, registry, .net-4.6.1

I'm using `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, view)` with both `RegistryView.Registry64` and `RegistryView.Registry32`.

When I try to read or write a key to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\Product` it is not using the `Wow6432Node` key and instead both views use the same path for both reading and writing.

Application itself is running as 32bit (confirmed in task manager).

To be clear I'm looking to selectively access the `Wow6432Node` key, not avoid it (which seems to be the common posted issue).

edit: Also I can manually add `Wow6432Node` to the path and that will work but I'd really like to avoid manually manipulating paths like that.

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this issue?

Comment: @n0ne I did not, I ended up having separate paths for RegistryView.Registry32 and RegistryView.Registry64. I didn't have to worry about RegistryView.Default. I still used the appropriate views on my calls though. This solution worked best for me because my code has full control over the paths as well as setting the hive/views.